# Cisco: No autostate on GigabitEthernet interfaces, any alternative? (not working)

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands, testing

I recently tried the command "no autostate" on a GigabitEthernet interface (on a newer router) and this didn't work anymore, does anyone know why this is occuring? This use to work on FastEthernet interfaces. Any alternative suggestions?

Working configuration: (Cisco router 881)

```
Interface vlan 2
no autostate
```

Not working: (Cisco router 1921)

```
Interface vlan 2
no autostate
```

Comment: I have to ask - why would you want to turn this off?

Comment: @JohnJensen When you set up vpn's for company's, they want to test the connectivity without having their LAN yet connected, so they ping their router that is present at that location. So it's used for test purposes.

Comment: Makes sense. What hardware platform are you working with?

Comment: What about putting the IP on a loopback instead for testing?

Comment: @DanielDib This could be a solution to test indeed. The only disadvantage with that setup is that you have to change it again to allow the user to eventually use his setup. With 'no autostate' you just put the interface in autostate again even when the connection is already used.

Comment: @MikePennington I was actually asking for an alternative too, I've added this to my question, this wasn't clear indeed.

Comment: @MikePennington I've added a specification of configuration and router.

Comment: I've only seen switchport autostate exclude on switches. For routers I've always used no keepalive. Have you tried that?

Comment: You just changed the configuration examples from "interface FastEthernet" to "interface vlan"... yet you're claiming that you really tried the examples on a real router.  This seems to be prima facie evidence that you aren't telling us what you really tried...

Comment: @MikePennington I didn't claim anything, I've given the situation like I remember it, when the other post mentioned keep alive, I realised I made a mistake in my question, this is only human. I wanted to know the answer to this question and already asked around and got my answer, see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research and questioning with cisco specialists, we can conclude that in newer versions of IOS and newer routers, autostate is applied by default and unchangeable. (so the "no autostate" will not work anymore on vlan's).

Comment: Do you have any references on this? I would love to read some more.

Comment: @JelmerS I've asked this question to one of the specialists I know. I'll ask a reference and get back 2 you.

Answer (score 4):

Because `autostate` is a feature of switch virtual interfaces (read: vlans.) From the horse's mouth: [[click here]](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps708/products_tech_note09186a0080160b14.shtml)

Perhaps you want `no keepalive`.

[edit] Oddly, [Feature Navigator](http://www.cisco.com/go/fn) only shows `autostate exclude` as available on cats.  However, my 1720 (WIC-4ESW) allows it. (12.4(23) IP/ADSL)

[edit 2] I just looked through the 1921 15.1(4)M1 universal image, and `autostate` is in there:

```
% strings -a C1900-UN.BIN | grep -i autostate
no autostate
autostate
Enable autostate determination for VLAN
```

Comment: Note: at the time the question read `int Fa0` and `int Ge0`

Comment: Indeed, srry about that, but this was pointed out by your question :) I've had the non-functionality with vlan's, that's why this is so strange to me.

Comment: @Bulki, unless I'm mistaken a Cisco 881 doesn't support Vlan interfaces... could you please post "show mod" output from both devices this has been tested on?

Comment: @MikePennington indeed, unless you add a HWIC

Comment: 881 has a built-in 4 port switch.

Comment: @RickyBeam, I looked at the data sheet... I stand corrected... you are right

Comment: @MikePennington google image search FTW

Comment: Cisco 881 does support VLANs on the Fa0-3 interfaces.

Comment: Strings doesn't help you there, the module dealing with autostate may have been compiled into the image, but the feature is non-functional because of lack of underlying infrastructure to work.

Comment: I'm just sayin' it's still in there.  That's not a comment on where it's still usable.